# Reversing a Custom Data Type

Tags: haskell

Consider the following data type for a length ordered list:

```
data LordL a = LordL Int [a] deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Here is a simple constructor:

```
LordL :: [a] -> LordL a
LordL xs = LordL (length xs) xs

ex) LordL [1,2,3] => LordL 3 [1,2,3]
```

Now i've been trying to implement a method which would consist of reversing the list but have not been able to get it working. Here is what i'v come up with:

```
rev xs = LordL (length xs) (reverse xs)
```

When I try and run the file this is the message i'm getting:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘LordL a’
```

Is there something I should be doing differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `rev` likely should take a `LordL a` object, so you can "unpack" the `Lordl` object, and reverse the list, so:

```
rev :: LordL a -> LordL a
rev (LordL l xs) = LordL l (reverse xs)
```

We do not have to recalculate the length, since the length of the reverse of a list is the same as the length of that list.